# Hangling touch events inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, event-handling, scrollview

I have a HorizontallScrollView and views inside it. I need to handle click and vertical moving by touch for each child. Is it possible? At the moment I set OnTouchListener and OnClickListener on every child inside scroll, but OnTouchListener conflicts with HorizontallScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in scrollView a gridView with your childs.